# Failed HFS+ disk diagnosing and recovery in Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery, hfs+

My external Lacie HDD failed recently. Unfortunately the drive contains a lot of critically important video files of which I had not made a backup.

I am very far from being a specialist in computer things, however I want to understand what kind of failure has happened.

I do not trust very much any local computer shop that offers data recovery... So I hope for an advice.

After connecting the drive to my Linux laptop I got this message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/misha/f97ff1ff-b7a4-37a1-9359-2289a9cf3f33: Command-line `mount -t "hfsplus" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/misha/f97ff1ff-b7a4-37a1-9359-2289a9cf3f33"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Could someone please explain the meaning of the message and recommend a possible way to fix the drive in Ubuntu. Or is it better to use some dedicated Macintosh programme?

Many many thanks,
Mikhail